# How to make this styling with css

Tags: css, header

[image]

how is it possible to do that, compatible, good looking and responsive ? I think to make the H2 box with a background, but it make a lot of problem interacting with the background... it's a lot of png. I prefer a way to do it with pure css, padding, margin etc

[full resolution image (too see texture)](http://studioteknik.ca/stackoverflow_question/cssline.jpg)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Comment: Chris Coyier, that guy ROCK !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with any semantically appropriate element of your choice, without having to set a background color.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/n2z0icvf

```
<h1>Technique</h1>

h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}

h1:before {
  right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

h1:after {
  left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: -50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/58JCY/

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>LEVE TECHNIQUE</legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border:none;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
}
legend {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: HTML elements should be chosen based on their meaning, not because of how they look.

Comment: @menardmam Without fieldset and legend, you can't have transparent background on the "text", you will need to assign a background color to the "text" to hide the line behind the "text", But you need a transparent background on the "text" to achieve what you need. That's why you need to use fieldset and legend.

Comment: @cimmanon what you said ?... good or bad to do it like that... it work fine for me!

Comment: @cimmanon I agree that HTML should be semantic, but we don't have the rest of his code and the question is asked as "Is it possible to do that".

Comment: I prefert your 3 line CSS technique.... but i need to be able to style it with h2, so the other technique win...